# Content-Security-Policy for Cordova not loading external scripts and stylesheets (404 error)

Tags: android, cordova, content-security-policy

I currently have the 'Content-Security-Policy' meta tag for Cordova set to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

If I run the Android emulator, I see the following error:

> Refused to load the stylesheet
>   'https://....min.css'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".

If I change the 'Content-Security-Policy' meta tag to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://* 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' https://* 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

I get the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

How do I fix this so I don't get a 404 error, and it loads remote stylesheets and scripts?

I am 100% sure that the remote file does exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add to config .xml :

```
<access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
```

and in index.html :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *;">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *">
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I am getting an error for fonts: Refused to load the font 'data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;base64,........' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.  Do you know how to set the 'Content-Security-Policy' so that fonts load as well?

Comment: I figured it out. Just add "font-src 'self' data:;" to both meta tags.

Comment: How do I do that if index.html is autogenerated?

Comment: At last, my ass has been saved. After about 1001 solutions, this is the one that has worked for me. Will you mind a glass of undiluted cognac?