# Is there anyway to use outside resourses in cordva, like api calls

Tags: cordova

I am very new at cordova (like first time using it), so please don't laugh at my attempts to figure this out. I have tried searching, but nothing really answers my questions.

It seems that everytime I try to an outside url it comes back with the error message

```
3029 Refused to connect to 'website' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

This is if I try to link to a website via iframe or through an api call. I understand this is for security, but is there a specific reason why everything seems to be blocked? It seems limiting on what you can do. And is there any way to get around this and connect to other sites without creating a huge security hole?

I will give an example of my ajax call for reference. Outside of the environment it works fine, but once in the cordova app I get the error above.

```
$.get({
    url: 'website',
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {
        apikey: key,
        objectType: 'something',
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.info(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

Comment: It says it in your error message, the content security policy is not set. Just set it up!

Comment: @Eric, and I would do that how?

Comment: @zazvorniki check this answear https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164045/content-security-policy-for-cordova-not-loading-external-scripts-and-stylesheets/48164642#48164642

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935021/how-to-define-content-security-policy-in-cordova-properly (first link on Google)